# Method is called automatically on object creation?

Tags: java

I can't understand the output of this code.

The class;

```
public class StaticMethodClass {

  public String str = display();

  public static String display() {
    System.out.println("Static Method");
    return "Hello";
  }

}
```

The main;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Main");
    StaticMethodClass methodClass = new StaticMethodClass();
    System.out.println(methodClass.str);
  }
```

Output;

```
Main
Static Method
Hello
```

Why is **display()** method called automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create an instance of the class it will need to initialize all the fields. Hence, the `display()` method is called to initialize `"str"`.

Answer (score 4):

Because, you called `display` method at the instance of class.

```
public String str = display();
```

Comment: But it is not static like `public static String str = display();` Why is it still called?

Comment: This method is called at the initialization of StaticMethodClass. `StaticMethodClass methodClass = new StaticMethodClass();`

Comment: @Mawia When you create an instance of a class, all the instance fields are initialized. `str` is also an instance field, but it's initializer is the invocation of a `static` method. That's perfectly fine. The method will be called to initialize the `str` field.

Comment: @RohitJain Oh! Damn it. Shame on me. I had no idea that fields are initialized at instance creation.

Comment: @Mawia No need to be ashamed of. Everyone makes mistakes :)

Comment: @Mawia Just a thought: When did you expect them to be initialized?

Answer (score 1):

The moment you create a new StaticMethodClass it initializes str by calling display().

Answer (score 0):

Because class member `str` is *initialized* with this method upon creation of object of class `StaticMethodClass`. You create an object in the `main()` method.